# Why is a callback function being converted to a JQuery.Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following code that should display a DIV then trigger a callback that shows a second DIV. For some reason whenever I execute it, the the `confirmPayment` function never gets executed. When I look at it in a debugger it says the `confirmPayment` callback is a `JQuery.Event` object and not a function. This doesn't make sense, any idea why this is occuring?

```
$(function(){
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
var confirmPayment = function(){
    socket.on('paid', function (data) {
        function confirmEmitter(callback){
            $('#confirmed').html(JSON.stringify(data)).show("slow");
            callback();
        };

        confirmEmitter(function(){
            socket.emit('confirmed', { my: 'Showing result' });
        });
    });
};

var sendPayment = function(confirmPayment){
    $('#submitted').html(d.method + '<br>' + d.note).show("slow");

            /////WHY IS THIS AN OBJECT?/////
            confirmPayment();
            /////WHY IS THIS AN OBJECT?/////
};
$('#doIt').click(sendPayment);

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters when you create the function. So the parameter `confirmPayment` on the function `sendPayment` is just the first parameter of this function, and when calling the function, the first argument to the function will be stored in `confirmPayment`.

Now this function get's called by jQuery's click event, and jQuery's [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event passes an [eventObject](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) as first parameter.

If you want to call the `confirmPayment` function from within `sendPayment`, just call it like `confirmPayment()`, but make sure you have no other variables defined with that name, because then you'll try to call that new variable.

So just remove the first parameter `confirmPayment` on `sendPayment`.

Answer (score 1):

`sendPayment` is registered as a event callback, so when jquery calls `sendPayment` it will pass the event as the first parameter.

In your case since `confirmPayment` is a closure function within the same scope you can just call `confirmPayment()` from `sendPayment`

```
var sendPayment = function(e){
    $('#submitted').html(d.method + '<br>' + d.note).show("slow");

            /////WHY IS THIS AN OBJECT?/////
            confirmPayment();
            /////WHY IS THIS AN OBJECT?/////
};
```